# RAW звук в Delphi

Tags: delphi, аудио

Нужна программка на делфи для преобразования текущей переменной типа real в звуковой формат, далее нужно проиграть через звуковую карту или подать на порт.

Спасибо.

Comment: Что значит преобразовать переменную в звуковой формат? У звука в компьютере есть как минимум два параметра: частота и громкость. А это два значения.

Comment: Переменная есть функция времени, а следовательно содержит и амплитуду и частоту. Real это числовая последовательность надо этот тип преобразовать в звуковой,например VAW, и передать на воспризведение или в порт ПК. Воспроизводить звук желательно в темпе  получения переменной real.

Answer (score 3):

Попробуйте [bass.dll](http://www.un4seen.com/bass.html), вот [ссылка](http://us.un4seen.com/files/bass24.zip) на архив, где есть заголовок (.pas) для делфи. Без знания сей библиотекия проиграл мп3 с диска через 15 мин, очень простая (и мощная) штука.

Я надеюсь, у вас не одна переменная типа REAL) В библиотеке есть функции, позволяющие подать на аудиовыход массив REAL.